# C++ read or overwrite variable depending on parameter

Tags: c++, variables, jsoncpp

it was difficult to find a precise title for the question, so if you have a better nameing, please help me out!

I am working on my program configuration with json, where I read hundreds of values from a json file with differnt file types (bool, string, integer, ...)

As it is right now, I have a save **AND** a read function and manually have to take care of the correct json-keys in **BOTH** of them. To improve it, I want to merge the two functions and just pass a parameter whether the program should save or read the values. My special requirement is, that I dont want to have redundant keys. So I dont want to use the json key or the variable name twice.

Here an example for a merged solution but still with the problem of double naming (redundancy):

```
int memory_variable = 0;
Json::Value config;

enum config_access{
    WRITE,
    READ
};

void handle_config(config_access mode) {
                               
    switch (mode) {

        case config_access::READ:
            config["test_value"] == memory_variable;
            break;

        case config_access::WRITE:
            memory_variable= config["test_value"].asInt();
            break;

    }
}
```

Does anybody has a smart idea how I could read or write from or to the local variable with one condition parameter at the top?

Note: I am using the JsonCpp from GitHub (https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)

---

Minimal reproducible code

```
#include <json/json.h>

int memory_variable = 0;
Json::Value config;

enum config_access {
    WRITE,
    READ
};

int load_json_file(std::string path, Json::Value& json_object) {

    std::string rawJson;

    std::ifstream file(path);

    if (file.fail()) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string line;

    while (getline(file, line)) {
        rawJson += line + "\n";
    }

    const auto rawJsonLength = static_cast<int>(rawJson.length());

    JSONCPP_STRING err;
    Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
    const std::unique_ptr<Json::CharReader> reader(builder.newCharReader());
    if (!reader->parse(rawJson.c_str(), rawJson.c_str() + rawJsonLength, &json_object, &err)) {
        std::cout << err << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void handle_config(config_access mode) {

    switch (mode) {

    case config_access::READ:
        config["test_value"] == memory_variable;
        break;

    case config_access::WRITE:
        memory_variable = config["test_value"].asInt();
        break;

    }
}

int main()
{
    load_json_file("C:/config.json", config);
    handle_config(config_access::READ);
}
```

Comment: Note: There is probably less room for programmer error if you have read and write functions and spin off the common code to its own function(s) to be called from the read and write functions.

Comment: I have to agree with user4581301. I don't understand why you would want to combine two distinct operations into a single method. You don't state a use case for that kind of requirement.

Comment: This is confusing. Why doesn't `handle_config` return the value when getting, and take another parameter when setting? `of double naming (redundancy):` I do not understand. What is the problem? So just store `config["test_value"]` in a reference?

Comment: Due to many nameing changes in the config file, I often had the problem that I forgot to transfer the name-changes to (lets say) the save function. So the value with the new name was read successfully but saved under the old name or the other way around. So I got annoyed by allways changing the key name in two differnt functions and started searching for solutions. Do you undertand, what I mean? Note that the program allways read all values at program start and allways save all values to discrete timepoints. If the read and write key differs, I run in problems.

Comment: My favourite solution would be a handle function, which gets three params. access_type (read/write), json_key as string and local_variable.. Do you know, how I can pass any c++ variable to a function and determine wether its a integer/bool/string?

Answer (score 1):

One way to make changes to the format easier to maintain is to store the config as a `Json::Value` and to provide getters and setters to it. To simplify reading/writing to files, add overloads to `operator<<` and `operator>>`.

Example:

```cpp
#include "json/json.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class Config {
public:
    // setters and getters
    void set_memory_variable(Json::Value::Int val) {
        json_value["memory_variable"] = val;
    }
    Json::Value::Int get_memory_variable() const {
        return json_value["memory_variable"].asInt();
    }

private:
    Json::Value json_value; // storing the internal configuration

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Config& conf) {
        // read configuration from any istream
        try {
            is >> conf.json_value;
        } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            std::clog << ex.what() << std::endl; // debug log
        }
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Config& conf) {
        // stream out all the config here
        return os << conf.json_value;
    }
};
```

Example usage:

*config.json*

```json
{
        "memory_variable" : 123
}
```

```cpp
int main() {
    if(std::ifstream file("config.json"); file) {   // open config file
        if(Config config; file >> config) {         // read config
            int val = config.get_memory_variable();

            val *= 2;
            config.set_memory_variable(val);        // update the internal value

            std::cout << config << '\n';            // write config to any ostream
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks intersteing. But I am not quite sure if I got it right. Like I said, I have hundreds of differnt variables, with differnt datatypes. How would I adopt this to your solution, which currently points to json_value["memory_variable"] ?

Comment: @gear I couldn't find a clean way of getting a proper proxy object fromt the `jsoncpp` `Json::Value` type directly so in that case you'd need to add a one-liner for the getter and a one-liner for the setter for each attribute in your config. Saving and restoring the data from file will not need to be touched because of the `operator<<` and `operator>>` overloads that solves that already. If you want a simpler interface, you could combine this with proxy objects as Jerry Coffin suggests in his answer. You need one for `Int`, one for `String` etc. and you could then reuse them all over.

Comment: ...or you could switch to using nlohmann's json library, which has a templated `as` function for reading values.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That'd be my choice too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than merging reading and writing into a single function, I'd probably just use variables for the keys you're using, and have both the functions for reading and writing use those variables for the keys.

```cpp
static char const *testKey = "test_value";

// ...

int readKey() { 
    return config[testKey].asInt();
}

void writeKey(int value) { 
    config[testKey] = value;
}
```

Alternatively, you might consider creating a class for a key:

```cpp
class intKey {
    std::string_view keyName;
public:
    key(std::string_view keyName) : keyName(keyName) {}

    key &operator=(int value) { 
        config[keyName] = value;
        return *this;
    }

    operator int() const {
        return config[keyName].asInt();
    }
};
```

In the latter case, you'd create an object, and reading from or writing to that key would look like reading or writing any other `int`:

```cpp
intKey configValue("TestKey");

// write
configValue = 1;

// read
int i = configValue;
```

Of course, it doesn't hurt to use both of these together, using a variable for the name of the key you supply to create the object (e.g., `intkey configValue(testKey);`).